# How to access a public type of an object

Tags: abap

I have a class named ZCL_RM_SPREADSHEETML.

It has in the Types tab a type called TY_STYLE with visibility 'Public' and it is defined with Direct Type Entry.

When I try to declare in the caller code the following :

```
DATA : wa_blue_style TYPE zcl_rm_spreadsheetml-ty_style.
```

I get the following:

```
The type "ZCL_RM_SPREADSHEETML" has no structure and therefore no
component called "TY_STYLE". .
```

This makes some sense I guess as ZCL_RM_SPREADSHEETML is a class, also double-clicking `TY_STYLE` does absolutely nothing.

Then I tried the following with a tilda:

```
DATA : wa_blue_style TYPE zcl_rm_spreadsheetml~ty_style.
```

I got the following:

```
Type "ZCL_RM_SPREADSHEETML~TY_STYLE" is unknown
```

Double clicking TY_STYLE will bring me though to the definition of TY_STYLE, so I must be close. The last time I had a similar issue it was because I was accessing a private method, but I marked the type clearly as Public.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I also tried per the comment

```
DATA : wa_blue_style TYPE ref to zcl_rm_spreadsheetml->ty_style. "and
DATA : wa_blue_style TYPE zcl_rm_spreadsheetml->ty_style.
```

which gives

```
Field "ZCL_RM_SPREADSHEETML" is unknown. It is neither in one of the
specified tables nor defined by a "DATA" statement.
```

Which gave me the idea to try this the 'class' way,

```
DATA : wa_blue_style TYPE zcl_rm_spreadsheetml=>ty_style.
```

**This works**

Comment: Did you try `DATA : wa_blue_style TYPE zcl_rm_spreadsheetml->ty_style.` Use the `->` instead the `-`.  (This is only a comment because I have no SAP available in the moment, so I can't test myself)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the appropriate [component selector](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abencomponent_selector_glosry.htm):

> Defined character that can be used to address components of upper units. There is a structure component selector (`-`), a class component selector (`=>`), an interface component selector (`~`), and an object component selector (`->`).

In this case, you're accessing a type (component) of a class, so you have to use `=>`.

Answer (score 1):

You meant this, right?

```
report  zstructsob.

*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&       Class MYCLASS
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*        Text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
class myclass definition.
  public section.

    types: begin of mystruct, " ------------> The public type
      field1 type i,
      field2 type string,
    end of mystruct.

    methods print_data importing data type mystruct.

  private section.
    data mydata type mystruct.
endclass.               "MYCLASS

*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&       Class (Implementation)  MYCLASS
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*        Text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
class myclass implementation.
  method print_data.
    write:/ data-field1, data-field2.
  endmethod.

endclass.               "MYCLASS

start-of-selection.

data ztype type myclass=>mystruct. " ------------> The public type of the class
data zclass type ref to myclass.

create object zclass.

ztype-field1 = 1.
ztype-field2 = 'Field2'.

zclass->print_data( ztype ).
```

Comment: I was actually referring to a type built into an SE80 object, not an in-line object. But yes, `=>` works in both cases.